# Error when I get json

Tags: android, json

I am use JSON in my application. I get json and have error

`Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"date":"","shirota":"53.5254","dolgota":"49.1684","imei":"44fd02f38e4a5c0c"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray"`

it is happens in row

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`. There is no `JSONArray`

```
{ // JSONObject node
    "date": "",
    "shirota": "53.5254",
    "dolgota": "49.1684",
    "imei": "44fd02f38e4a5c0c"
}
```

This

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Should be

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: result = {"imei":"44fd02f38e4a5c0c","dolgota":"49.4098","shirota":"53.5409","date":"2014\/05\/13 11:41:43"}{"imei":"a2422857b2cccf4c","dolgota":"49.4385","shirota":"53.5142","date":"2014\/05\/13 11:22:09"}

Comment: @user3176367 i still don't see a jsonarray in what you posted in the above comment